# Accessing the Identity object in a MVC repository

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller, repository, design-patterns

I have a pretty generic repository that does basic CRUD for many of my business entities.
The entities enherit form a generic object that has a few fields I maintain for all objects.
eg. ModifiedBy, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate.

These fields ModifiedBy and CreatedBy will always be set before any update/save.

My questions is: 
Is there any way to gain access to the Identity object from my MVC web application in my repositories?
I was hoping to set the modifiedby to the identity user for any update in one shot??

Best Regard,
Rod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could access `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` directly in your repositories, but I wouldn't recommend it as it will make your repositories HttpContext-dependent.

Alternatives:

- Add an explicit `IIdentity` parameter in your Create/Update methods, e.g. `void Update(T entity, IIdentity user)`
- Decouple the logic of "getting the current user", e.g.:

  ```
  class GenericRepository<T>: IRepository<T> {
      private readonly ICurrentUserFetcher currentUserFetcher;
      public GenericRepository<T>(ICurrentUserFetcher currentUserFetcher) {
          this.currentUserFetcher = currentUserFetcher;
      }
      public void Update(T entity) {
          var currentUser = currentUserFetcher.Get();
          ...
      }
  }
  interface ICurrentUserFetcher {
      IIdentity Get();
  }
  class WebCurrentUserFetcher: ICurrentUserFetcher {
      public IIdentity Get() {return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;}
  }
  ```

  Or even simpler:

  ```
  class GenericRepository<T>: IRepository<T> {
      private readonly Func<IIdentity> currentUserFetcher;
      public GenericRepository<T>(Func<IIdentity> currentUserFetcher) {
          this.currentUserFetcher = currentUserFetcher;
      }
      public void Update(T entity) {
          var currentUser = currentUserFetcher();
          ...
      }
  }
  var repo = new GenericRepository<Person>(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
  ```

  Use an IoC container to wire things up.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, you hvae given me some great alternatives. I was trying to avoid coupling with the http context, so I think I will attempt the second option.

Comment: I am a little confused about how the person in the article seems to be implementing the ICurrentUserFetcher for the second example. I assume that it would provide the extra properties that are not available from the IIdentity.  Could someone please provide clarity on this code as it would come in handy for something I have to do?

Comment: I am new to the Unity container or any IoC container in all honesty.  How would I inject the IIdentity into the Repository?

Comment: @user1790300 It's `Func<IIdentity>`, not `IIdentity`. No idea about Unity, try the docs or create a new, more specific question.