# WebApi External Bearer Authentication and Injecting User into respositories

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, controller, authorization

I have a webapi project and a repositories project.

I have configured to use oauth, which uses owin middleware bearer token authentication.

I have a unitofwork with multiple repositories.

Inside the repositories I want to filter data based on the logged on user.

I would like all repositories to get the logged in user via dependency injection.

I can access the logged on user in the webapi action, but I am struggling to work out if/how I can inject the current user using DI; because the authorization is happening via the webapi Authorize?:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public IQueryable<Folder> Folders()
    {
       // return UnitOfWork.FolderRepository.All().OrderBy(o=>o.FolderId).Skip(10).Take(50);
        var test = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        //test is populated with the logged on user here, but I don't want to set the user details of the UOW in every action in my controllers
        return UnitOfWork.FolderRepository.All();
    }
```

So in the action Folders the Authorize annotation logs the user on.  But I have already instantiated the unit of work in the controller constructor with DI:

```
public FolderController(IUnitOfWork uow, UserManager<IdentityUser,int> usermanager)
    {
        UnitOfWork = uow;
        UserManager = usermanager;
    }
```

IOC container:

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

            x.For<HttpContextBase>()
                .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                .Use(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));

            x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use(
                () => new UnitOfWork(new BreezeValidator
                                        (new UserManager<AspNet.Identity.SQLServer.IdentityUser, int>(new UserStore(new SqlDatabase()))))
            );
       }
 }
```

I had tried to pass in HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(), but at that point the authorization hasn't taken place and so the Principal has not been set.

I have looked at actionfilters (which are run after the authorization filter), but can't figure out how I would return a new unit of work instance with the logged on user set, back to the controller.

...Or whether I can set a property on the controller from an action filter?

So the question is really, how can I set the user details in all my controller's unitofwork, without lots of duplication?

Thanks

EDIT:  I have a working solution, but still not sure it's the right way to go:

I created an action filter and then from there get the controller and set a UserPrincipal property on the controller's unitOfWork property.

```
using Project1.Web.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace Project1.Web.Filters
{
public class InjectUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var action = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
            UowApiController ctrl = (UowApiController)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
            ctrl.UnitOfWork.UserPrincipal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
        }

}
```

Then, in my UnitOfWork setter of the UserPrincipal I set the UserPrincipal in the contained repositories:

```
public IPrincipal UserPrincipal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userPrincipal;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userPrincipal = value;

            ((Repository<Folder>)FolderRepository).UserPrincipal = value;
        }
    }
```

This works now, but it doesn't achieve dependency injection.

Also I would like to know if this is a "right" way to do it, or what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and decided on this. I think this answer will be relevant to you as well. 
[Proper way to dependency inject authenticated user to my repository class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742633/proper-way-to-dependency-inject-authenticated-user-to-my-repository-class)

I've just added a getter to the service classes that accesses the user identity at request time.

```
public class MyService
{
    //ctor...

    public IEnumerable<Results> GetResults()
    {
        return _ResultRepository.GetResultsByUser(UserIdentity);
    }

    IIdentity UserIdentity
    {
        get { return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity; }
    }
}
```